# Golang template interprets html as plain text

Tags: html, go

I have a Golang template interpreting my html as plain text.

I have included the line `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")` in my function passed to `http.HandleFunc()` however nonetheless my html is interpreted as plain text.

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/dog", dog)
    http.Handle("/resources/", http.StripPrefix("/resources", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets"))))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.gohtml"))
}

func dog(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    data := []string{`<h1>This is from dog</h1>`, `<img src="/assets/img/dog.jpg">`}
    tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", data)
}
```

And here is my `index.gohtml` template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{range .}}
        {{.}}
    {{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Convert your strings to https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML, either in the Go code, or inside the template by registering a func that does that. E.g. `[]template.HTML{\`<h1>This is from dog</h1>\`, \`<img src="/assets/img/dog.jpg">\`}`

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva that did the trick.  I will answer below for others to learn from this.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the answer is to replace `[]string{}` with `[]template.HTML{}` instead when passed as data into your template.